# string + string VS += in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, performance, concatenation

space and/or perfomance wise, what would be a more efficient way to add strings, in the case of having many string literals concatenated together, in Javascript?

`x += y;`
OR
`x + y`;
I've been pondering about this for a while. Of course for a case where there are only two strings being concatenated together there would be virtually no difference, but what about cases where a CSS or html document is being structured inside the JS, or a huge XML, for whatever reason?

```js
string += " classA {}";
...
.....
string += "classX {}";
```

VS

```js
string + "classA {}" +
...
.....
+ "classX {}";
```

Sorry if this sounds like a basic question, but I had a similar problem when I had to code an XML parser in Java and realized the usage of StringBuilder. Not sure how this translates to JavaSript.

Comment: `x += y` changes the value of `x`. `x + y` evaluates the expression but does not change either of the variables. So the answer will depend partly on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+string+concatenation+performance&oq=javascript+string+concatenation+performance

Comment: @Jayce444 yes, but just quickly checked the top 3 results and they are completely outdated. One even recommends `String#concat` where MDN strongly discourages the use of that method for performance reasons.

Comment: I vastly prefer array.push for readability: `const strings = []; strings.push("classA {}"); .... strings.push("classX {}"); return strings.join(" ");` for example. Also consider [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: ＠Jayce alot of those comparisons compare it with arrays and not what I looked for, and refer to a time where IE was one of the most well used browser.

Comment: However, I still need to support IE, so @mplungjan unfortunately template literal with back-ticks is not possible due to no support.

I really just wonder if there is a difference between x + y + .... + z, and doing the same with +=, and if not then what's a StringBuilder-like eifficient way of managing large strings.

Comment: There are several examples of creating a StringBuilder using javascript - but all are similar to this one [StringBuilder in javascript](https://the-sourceterous.ghost.io/stringbuilder-in-javascript/) as they rely on using an array and then performing a join() operation to concatenate all the strings.

Comment: `x += y` is just a shorthand for `x = x + y`, there's no performance difference.

Comment: @Teemu The question is not for that, read again, I realize there's no performance difference in that case. it's in a case of many concatenations, would doing a "one-take" line ala `x = x + y + z + a + b + c ....` would be faster than adding each of these on a separate line with `x += a` or not

Comment: ?? The optimized compile result is still the same, there's no difference. If you're using some old interpreting JS engine, your worries about performance should be focused totally to other features than string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to modify `x`? More specifically, does it matter if `x` gets modified?

`x + y` on its own doesn't do anything unless used as an argument or captured to a variable. `let z = x + y` does, as does `f(x + y)`.

`x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y` and so modifies `x`, which may or may not be what you want.

Normally if your intent is to "append to `x`" and save the result then you'd say `x += y`.

If your intent is to use the combined `x` and `y` in some other place, such as `f(x + y)`, then that's appropriate. Here `f(x += y)` sends mixed messages, as it's not clear why you'd be appending *and* calling.

Comment: They both end up in a variable. My question is more or less about clearing the ambiguity of "string + string";
It's clear that (afaik) when using +=, the previously defined `x` gets `y` added to it by recalling itself and adding `y` into it. When you do this repeatedly, the concatenation gets quite large.

I guess it's more a question of if there's something like `StringBuilder` for Javascript.

Comment: If you have `x = x + y` then it's easier to express as `x += y`. If you have `f(x + y)` or `let z = x + y` then that's a different situation. If you're doing repeated concatenation I wouldn't worry about it *until you have a measurable performance problem*. JavaScript is really, really good at handling string data and does it efficiently even if intuitively you might think it's slow or inefficient. Many people have worked very hard to get that kind of performance out of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's purely your own choice. How you're comfortable doing. Doesn't have any specific standard to it. I could argue that when using `x += y` when you have to use multiple statements between the string declaration & modification. However, again it still comes down to your own choice.